# /etc/security/limits.conf: Permission denied error even with sudo su used

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, superuser

```
echo "USERNAME - nice -20

USERNAME - rtprio 99" >> /etc/security/limits.conf
```

I need to add sudo su to this in order to access /etc. I've tried adding sudo su to both lines, but I still get a permission denied error.

how do i fix this? Thanks
I'm on pop os 22.04

Comment: This would be more apporporiate on `server fault` or `super user`

Comment: Yes.  Stack overflow is for programming.  Questions on how or why bash commands work or don't work is more of a superuser topic.

Comment: The redirection is happening in your original shell, even if you use `sudo echo`.